# Why does node.js suddenly use less memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I have a 25MB json file, that I "require" why my app starts up. Initial it seems that the node.js process takes up almost 200MB of memory.

But if I leave it running and come back to it, Activity monitor reports that it is using only 9MB which makes no sense at all! At the very least, it should be a few MB more, since even a simple node.js app that does almost nothing (acting like a server), uses 9MB.

The app seems to work fine - it is a server, that provides search suggestions form a word list of 220,000 words.

Is Activity Monitor wrong ?
Why is it using only 9MB, but initially used ~200MB when the application started up ?

Comment: Because it did stuff that used a lot of memory, then that memory got GCed?

Comment: It'll be initially using a chuck of memory to load the program and compile it, once it's done it'll clear out a fair bit.  Doubt that would account for 200mb mind.

Comment: Loading a 25mb string and processing it is gonna be costly, but once that's happened, all the memory required to parse 25mb of json can be collected, leaving only a (leaner) in-memory structure.

Comment: Its hard to estimate the size of a JSON object (i've already looked into that in various other posts), but a JSON object containing over 220,000 strings each 5-7 characters in length, as well as other data should use more space right ? If 2 bytes per character, then at least 10 bytes per string which means around 2.2 MB ??? Did I get that estimate correct ? Then it really should be only 2MB after GC! Am I right ? Also, all I did was "require" the file. Nothing else. So it is something that node is doing internally.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's JavaScript things that are no longer being used are removed via Garbage Collector(GC), freeing memory. Everything (or many things) may have been loaded into memory at the start. Then items that were not longer needed were removed from memory by the GC. Usually generation can take more memory in progress and lose some afterwards, for example temporary data-structures can be used in progress but are not longer needed when the process is done.

It's also possible that items in memory where swapped out and written to the disk temporally (and may be later retrieved), this swapping this is done by your OS and tends to be used more on programs that reserve a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

**How much memory it takes to load the file depends on a number of factors**.

**What text encoding is being used to store the file?** JavaScript uses UTF-16 internally, so if that's not what's being used on disk, the size may be different. If the file is in UTF-32, for example, then the in-memory UTF-16 version will be smaller unless it's full of astrals. If the file is in UTF-8, then things are reversed: the in-memory version will be larger unless it's full of astrals. But for now, let's just assume that they're about the same size, either because they use the same encoding or the pattern of astrals just happens to make the file sizes more or less the same.

**You're right that it takes at least 25MB to load the file (assuming that encodings don't interfere)**. The semantics of the JSON API being what they are, you need to have the whole file in memory as a string, so the app will take up at least that much memory at that time. That doesn't count whatever the parser needs to run, so you need at least 34MB: 25 for the file, 9 for Node, and then whatever your particular app uses for itself.

**But your app doesn't need all of that memory all the time.** Depending on how you've written the app, you're probably destroying your references to the file at some point. 
Because of the semantics of JSON, there's no way to avoid loading the whole file into memory, which takes 25MB because that's the size of the file. There's also no way to avoid taking up whatever memory the JSON parser needs to do its work and build the object.

But depending on how you've written the app, there probably comes a point when you no longer need that data. Either you exit the function that you used to load the file, or you assign that variable to something else, or any of a number of other possibilities. However it happens, **JavaScript reclaims memory that's not being used anymore**. This is called *garbage collection*, and it's popular among so-called "scripting languages" (though other programming languages can use it too).

**There's also the question of text representation versus in-memory representation**. Strings require about the same amount of space in memory versus on-disk, unless you change the encoding, but Numbers and Booleans are another matter entirely. In JavaScript, all Numbers are 64-bit floating-point numbers, so if most of your numbers on disk are more than four characters long, then the in-memory representation will be smaller, possibly by quite a bit. Note that I said characters, not digits: it's true that digits are characters, but +, -, e, and . are characters too, so -1e0 takes up as twice as much space as -1 when written as text, even though they represent the same value in memory. As another example, 3.14 takes up as much space as 1000 as text (and happen to take up the same amount of space in memory: 64 bits each). But -0.00000001 and 100000000 take up much less space in memory than on disk, because the in-memory representation is smaller. Booleans can be even smaller: different engines store them in different ways, but you could theoretically do it in as little as one bit. That's a far cry from the 8 bytes it takes to store "true", or 10 to store "false".

**So if your data is mostly about Numbers and Booleans, then the in-memory representation stands to get a lot smaller. If it's mostly Strings, then not so much.**